# Spawn MC addChild to stage but how to tie in the draggable function? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, addchild

I'm running into some problems with making the movie clip so I can drag it about the stage. The scenario: the user clicks a button that spawns the movie clip to the stage, from there they can move the item around the stage - it's a draggable object. I can make it so the movieClip spawns, I can make it so it drags... but i can't make it do both, once I try to attach the drag function. Any pointers please? I'm new to as3! :-)

```
spawner_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnspinkjewel);

function spawnspinkjewel(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  var myChild:pink_jewel= new pink_jewel();
  stage.addChild(myChild)
myChild.x=300; 
    myChild.y=150;
} 
pink_jewel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupblack_pink_jewel);
pink_jewel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropblack_pink_jewel);

function pickupblack_pink_jewel(event:MouseEvent):void {
event.target.startDrag(true);
}
function dropblack_pink_jewel(event:MouseEvent):void {
event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the listeners to the incorrect object.

Change this:

```
pink_jewel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupblack_pink_jewel);
pink_jewel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropblack_pink_jewel);
```

To this:

```
myChild.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupblack_pink_jewel);
myChild.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropblack_pink_jewel);
```

Comment: Hello, that looks simple enough thanks. I will have a tanker when I get the chance.

Comment: Hello, okay still a bit stuck then. The movieclip appears on the stage... but I can't drag the object. It appears above my cursor, and I have moved my cursor to the top layer of the timeline. Any clues or suggestions?

Comment: Try this in your start and stop drag: `(e.target as MovieClip).startDrag( true );` and then `(e.target as MovieClip).stopDrag()` respectively.